# How to open a checked out file P4 Python

Tags: python, perforce, p4python

I am currently writing a script in Python with the P4Python API which automates the process of checking out a file in Perforce and making some changes to it. I'm currently trying to figure out how to open the file which has been checked out so I can make changes to it but I cannot open it using the "//depot" file path. I'd assume I need to use the system file path (C:/...) but I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
## Connect to P4 server
p4.connect()

## Checkout file to default changelist
p4.run_edit("//depot/file/tree/fileToEdit.txt")

f1 = "//depot/file/tree/fileToEdit.txt" ## This file path does not work

with open(f1, 'w') as file1:
    file1.write("THIS IS A TEST")

## Disconnect from P4 server
p4.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following bit of code provided me with the local file path:

```
result = p4.run_fstat("//depot/file/tree/fileToEdit.txt")[0]['clientFile']
print(result)
```

Using p4.run_fstat("//depot/filename") will provide all the information necessary, the additional "[0]['clientFile']" was to pull the local file path.

Answer (score 2):

Python's `open` function operates on local files and has no concept of depot paths, so as you say, you need to use the workspace path.  Conveniently, this is returned as part of the `p4 edit` output so you can just grab it from there:

```
from P4 import P4

p4 = P4()

## Connect to P4 server
p4.connect()

## Checkout file to default changelist
local_paths = [
    result['clientFile'] 
    for result in p4.run_edit("//depot/file/tree/fileToEdit.txt")
]

for path in local_paths:
    with open(path, 'w') as f:
        f.write("THIS IS A TEST")

## Disconnect from P4 server
p4.disconnect()
```

Note that this simple script will not work in a case where the `p4 edit` command doesn't open the file, e.g. if the file is not synced (in which case maybe your script wants to `p4 sync` it), or if the file is already open (in which case maybe you just want to get the local path from `p4 opened` and modify it anyway -- or maybe you want to revert the existing changes first, or maybe do nothing at all), or if the file does not exist (in which case maybe you want to `p4 add` it instead).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response! I ran into the following error when implementing this code: 
  File ".\P4Connect.py", line 24, in <module>
    local_paths = [
  File ".\P4Connect.py", line 25, in <listcomp>
    result['clientFile']
TypeError: string indices must be integers.
I've tried adding an integer into the "Result[]" section, but this would lead to a permission error later when trying to open the file.

Comment: Since your original question didn't include your entire script I can only guess at why it's working differently for you, but my guess is that your script disables tagged output and so `run_edit` is giving you a list of strings rather than a list of dictionaries.  If that's not it (the fix would be as simple as removing a `p4.tagged = False` line) tne of the first steps in debugging this would be to examine the value of `result` to see what that string is.

Comment: I've taken a look at the value for "print(result)" and it returns the following: "//depot/file/tree/fileToEdit.txt#23 - currently opened for edit". I'm not sure how I can retrieve the system file path to this point and there doesn't seem to be much documentation regarding this.

Comment: Like I said in my answer: "this simple script will not work in a case where the `p4 edit` command doesn't open the file".  You're hitting the case where it's already open.  Figure out what you want your script to do in that case, and make the appropriate adjustements.

Comment: If I were writing this script, I'd probably do some pre-flight checks with `p4 fstat` to validate that the file is in the expected state (is it synced to the head rev?  is it open already?  does it even exist?) before even trying to open it.  But I don't know what the overall goal of the script is so maybe it's appropriate to just have it raise an exception if it's not in the "happy path"?

Comment: File is synced using p4.run_sync prior to opening it for edit. The only thing I need to know now is how I can actually edit this file that is already opened. The end goal of the script is to be able to copy some lines from a text file on my desktop and write it in the file thats currently checked out and open for edit in perforce.

Comment: If you know ahead of time that the file is already open for edit, why does the script try to open it for edit?  Just use `p4 have` to get the local path if you don't already know it (although I'm not sure why you wouldn't know that ahead of time as well since you're the one who set up the workspace).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221969/discussion-between-rayh99-and-samwise).